# Преобразовать Email

Tags: php

Ребят, необходимо преобразовать любой входящий емаил по такому правилу

`aaaaaaa@gmail.com => a***@gmail.com`

`bb@gmail.com => b***@gmail.com`

Т.е. от первой части емайла оставить первую букву и три звездочки.

Не могу понять как сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
$string = 'aaaaaaa@gmail.com';
// запоминаем первую букву
$firstLetter = substr($string, 0, 1);
// заменяем то, что до собачки звездочками, остальное не трогаем
// и добавляем первую букву в начало
$pattern = '/([\.\-_A-Za-z0-9]+?)(@[\.\-A-Za-z0-9]+?[\ .A-Za-z0-9]{2,})/';
$replacement = '***${2}';

echo $firstLetter.preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

`preg_replace`- Выполняет поиск и замену по регулярному выражению http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

`substr` - Возвращает подстроку из входной строки http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php

Второй вариант:

```
$string = 'test@gmail.com';
$parts = explode('@', $string);
echo substr($parts[0], 0, 1).'***@'.$parts[1];
```

`explode` - Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя. Возвращает массив строк, полученных разбиением строки `string` с использованием `delimiter` в качестве разделителя. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант на javascript...

```js
var str = 'anton@gmail.com';

var a = str.charAt(0); // a
var b = str.split('@')[0]; // anton (строчка для примера)
var c = str.split('@')[1]; // gmail.com

var res = a + '***@' + c;

alert(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно разделить через split('@'), потом первую часть засунуть в массив символов, оставить первую букву и добавить звездочки